Interpretation of "measured in pages" for /proc/[pid]/statm
The man page for the proc file system says that memory usage for /proc/[pid]/statm and others is "measured in pages". I'm not sure what this means when multiple page sizes are used.
Let's say my process uses two pages, one 4KiB page and one 2MiB page, and sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) returns 4096 bytes. Which of the following results will proc/[pid]/statm return in this case?

2, because the process is using one 4KiB page and one 2MiB page.
513, because the process uses 2101248 bytes and this is divided by the "default" page size (4096 bytes).


You’ll see 513 — the values are shown in “default” pages. You can compare with the values in kiB given in /proc/[pid]/status; the equivalences are given in man 5 proc_pid_statm.
See proc_pid_statm and task_statm in the kernel source code for reference (if that’s meaningful to you).
